# .NET Core exclude a class from project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

How can I exclude a class from a project in **.NET CORE**

I don't see a `context-menu` option in **Visual Studio 2015** for excluding a file.

Read couple of areas on how to exclude it https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1464 and tried to do the following

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore": "1.5.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "System.Linq": "4.1.0",
    "System.Xml.XmlSerializer": "4.0.11"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "compile": {
      "excludeFiles": [
        "security/securityutility.cs",
        "httpcontext/contextutility.cs",
        "excel/parse.cs"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is the exclude section, since I have some compile time errors in those files, I want to exclude those files and continue with the project.

```
"buildOptions": {
    "compile": {
      "excludeFiles": [
        "security/securityutility.cs",
        "httpcontext/contextutility.cs",
        "excel/parse.cs"
      ]
    }
  }
```

But that doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: This works for me (version 1.0.0-rc2). When you say "exclude", you mean just exclude from compilation, not from the project? Is your project.json in the root of the project?

Comment: I am building single class Library. and I have project.json in root of this project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can't remove a file from project as you could in *.csproj projects.

In *.xproj/project.json projects all files will be included by default.

The compile `exclude` and `excludeFiles` options is for the compiler, when you build the project.

When you're in Visual Studio Roslyn will compile/validate the syntax as you edit, so I **believe** there is no way to prevent/exclude within Visual Studio, other then commenting out the whole file/affected code.

You can still compile your code even if Visual Studio/Roslyn shows the red curly errors lines, when you exclude that file. I just tested it.

But it's annoying.

Comment: That sucks! in CORE. How could Microsoft do such a stupid job :(

Comment: Well, they are looking into ways to replace/merge the project.json back into csproj, but this won't happen until next major version of ASP.NET Core/.NET Core, nothing set in stone yet. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/